# How does LoadRunner Controller designate Vuser IDs?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

So I have a few scripts to run in the controller, I am wondering how it actually allocates vuser ids.

Does it go through each Vuser list and allocate it a Vuser ID something like:

Script 1 1,5,9

Script 2 2,6,10

Script 3 3,7,11

Script 4 4,8,12

Or will it allocate the User Count based on the script so 3 users in Script 1 will give 1,2,3 for instance. If need be I can give more detail, just cant think how to explain it!

Or will it do it in a different method?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuser ID-s are allocated in the scope of a Vusers group. 
Every time a vuser is added a new ID, greater than the previously assigned ID is allocated. Removing vusers will not “release” IDs of removed vusers.
In the Controller we provide feature to “renumber” vusers. Actually it reallocates IDs starting from 1, but **still in scope of vuser groups**.

This answer was kindly provided by an HP expert

Comment: Just to clarify, I **asked** an HP expert and this is the reply I got from him :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question.   Uniqueness is enforced if this is your concern.    My working hypothesis is that it would be as you add users to the scenario that this then would be the sequence.   Since most people add a group at a time it would appear sequential by group.   You can view the virtual user numbers on the run screen details for the group to check your thoughts on numbering as users are added versus ramped up/executed.

Comment: I apologise for not being able to give a lot of detail it was hard to word it in my head let alone in writing! Thanks for your help though I will have a look at the Controller and the VUser Log as well to try and determine the numbering from ramp up and waiting times following the previous iteration. Thanks again.